# Elementos de entrada fora da tag form

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber se é considerado uma má pratica atributos de entrada fora da tag form.

> Em [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)

*A marca `<form>` é usada para criar um formulário HTML para a entrada do usuário.
O elemento `<form>` pode conter um ou mais dos seguintes elementos de formulário:*

```
<input>
<textarea>
<button>
<select>
<option>
<optgroup>
<fieldset>
<label>
```

> Em [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

*O elemento HTML `<form>` representa uma seção de um documento que contém controles interativos que permitem ao usuário submeter informação a um determinado servidor web.*

É correto usar tais atributos sem chamadas HTTP?, isso afeta em algo relacionado a validação de código HTML?

Comment: Se você validar as páginas na maioria dos validadores de HTML com certeza irão aparecer erros de elementos sem form, ou form sem elementos. Em questões de SEO creio não ter nenhum problema, em questões de programação acho que também não. Talvez teria caso queira carregar esses valores entre páginas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende o que você está considerando como "validação do código HTML". Se for o resultado de ferramentas de validação de HTML que são possíveis encontrar pela internet, inclusive da W3C, sim, existe a possibilidade do seu arquivo se tornar inválido. Isso importa? Não. Pois se considerar como validação as definições e especificações da W3C, que é um consórcio que define os padrões web, o seu arquivo HTML continuará válido.

Na própria documentação no MDN é possível verificar:

> **Elementos pais permitidos** Qualquer elemento que aceite conteúdo fraseado.

Ou seja, qualquer elemento que aceite conteúdo fraseado poderá conter elementos `input`, `button`, `select`, etc. Perceba que em nenhum momento é descrito que obrigatoriamente precisa estar dentro de um elemento `form`.

A própria [especificação da W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) trás esse mesmo trecho:

> **Contexts in which this element can be used**: Where phrasing content is expected.

É considerado má prática utilizá-los fora do `form`? Não necessariamente. A pergunta correta a se fazer é: faz sentido na minha aplicação eu utilizá-los assim? Se a resposta é afirmativa, pode usá-los sem problemas. Inclusive é comum desenvolvedores utilizarem outros elementos de forma equivocada com o medo de utilizar tais elementos "de formulário". Um exemplo clássico é utilizar um elemento de âncora, `a`, para abrir uma janela modal; semanticamente seria melhor utilizar o próprio `button`, mesmo fora de um formulário ou para enviar informações ao servidor.

Comment: Esse trecho realmente me passou despercebido, mas em relação a pergunta, 'fazer sentido', praticamente tudo em front faz, você tem a liberdade de definir por exemplo ul´s e li´s para substituir um select, faz sentido? faz, muitos frameworks usam isso, é correto? creio que não, é um hack, muita gente não sabe que ali não existe um select, mas enfim, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Nem sempre faz. Pode funcionar e pode não fazer sentido ao mesmo tempo. Já teve pergunta aqui de usuário querendo utilizar o *checkbox* como *radio* só porque era quadrado. Funciona? De certa forma, sim, quando tomado todos os cuidados. Faz sentido? Nenhum um pouco.

Answer (score 1):

Não é considerado uma má pratica não, desde que gere um boa interface e que faça sentido.

Por exemplo um botão de resetar dados, ou limpar um feed, podem estar fora de form.

Mais informações:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1